# format and display a phone number on a report page in PHP

Tags: php, phone-number

I have a database field called `customer_phone` that is stored as it was inputted. It is displayed on a report page now from the database like this:

```
print  "Phone: $customer_phone<br>";
```

I'd like to get the data from the database field, strip out any extra characters if any to just numbers (ex: `xxx-xxx-xxxx` to `xxxxxxxxxx`) and then display it on the page in this format:

```
(xxx) xxx-xxxx
```

I've found function scripts to do this but haven't been able to get them to work.

I need to get the data from the database field, re-format it and display it on the page.

I'm a PHP newby and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 14):

```
function format_telephone($phone_number)
{
    $cleaned = preg_replace('/[^[:digit:]]/', '', $phone_number);
    preg_match('/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/', $cleaned, $matches);
    return "({$matches[1]}) {$matches[2]}-{$matches[3]}";
}
```

There's a function to do as you asked, call it like

```
<?php echo format_telephone($customer_phone); ?>
```

Comment: No Problem, if you be so kind as to decide a winner and accept an answer we would appreciate it :)

Answer (score 4):

```
$phone_number= preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $phone_number); //Strip all non number characters
echo preg_replace("/([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})/", "($1) $2-$3", $phone_number) //Re Format it
```